# How can I add a scroll bar to an overlay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a simple overlay, as the one in the picture, and I need to know how to make a scroll bar inside the overlay. So, the overlay is the blue box, which get displayed after clicking `cart` button and vice versa.

I want to add a scroll bar after reaching specific height.

Please let me know with how to do it with a simple code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing the scrollbar on the blue box, you need to set a height and overflow property to the blue box.

.blue_box{
min-height: 2rem,
overflow-y: scroll,
max-height: 12rem,
}

Comment: So `overflow-y: scroll` is setting the scroll bar, right?

Comment: max-height is important too.